# Why does the WordPress add_filter not work for me?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want the first letters of words in the title to be uppercase. It does nothing, nothing changes.

```
   add_filter('the_title', function(){
   return ucwords($content);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't accept a $content parameter.

```
add_filter("the_title", function($content, $id = null) {
    return ucwords($content);
});
```

(Also, just a warning, this won't work for PHP versions before 5.3 due to the anonymous function).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
add_filter( 'the_title',   
'capitalized_wp_titles_convert');
function capitalized_wp_titles_convert ($title) {
    $title = ucwords($title);
}
```